# Problem to delete a row from a table with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to remove a row from a simple table using a simple button.

I try to use the index but with what I wrote, when I click on the line to delete, it is only all the others that are deleted ...

I guess the problem comes from the way I use the index but I have some difficulties to understand the behavior.

```
 let users = [
        { firstName: "John", lastName: "Connor", age: 20 },
        { firstName: "Geralt", lastName: "Rivia", age: 45 },
        { firstName: "Nathan", lastName: "Drake", age: 36 }
    ]
    
    
    class exercice extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                users: users
            }
        }
        
        onClickDeleteRow = index => {
            users = users.splice(index,1)
            this.setState({users: users})
            console.log(this.state.users)
        }
        
    
        render() {
            let usersName = this.state.users.map((user, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                    <td>{user.firstName} </td>
                    <td>{user.lastName} </td>
                    <td><button onClick={() => this.onClickDeleteRow(index)}>Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            ))
    
            return (
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> firstName </th>
                            <th> lastName</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {usersName}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            )
        }
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(
        <div className="firstContainer">
            <Exercice />
        </div>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

`.splice()` method returns an array containing the elements that were removed from the original array on which `.splice()` method was called. So if `index` is 1, then

```
users = users.splice(index,1)
```

will update `users` and assign an array containing one element to the `users` constant. If `index` is 1 then after the above statement, `users` will be

```
users = [{ firstName: "Geralt", lastName: "Rivia", age: 45 }]
```

which is what gets set in the state. That is why all other rows are removed except the one that you wanted to delete.

#### Solution

You could solve the problem in couple of ways:

1. Change

   ```
   users = users.splice(index, 1);
   ```

   to

   ```
   users.splice(index, 1);
   ```

   this will make sure that you don't update the `users` with the return value of `.splice()` method.
2. Problem with the first approach is that it modifies the original `users` array. You could avoid modifying the `users` array by using the `.filter()` method.

   Change the `onClickDeleteRow` method as shown below:

   ```
   onClickDeleteRow = (index) => {
      const updatedUsers = this.state.users.filter((user, idx) => idx !== index);
      this.setState({ users: updatedUsers });
   };
   ```

Comment: Nice answer - very well explained.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great explanation, it helped me a lot!
Everything is working fine. I have another little question related to calling onClickDeleteRow in the render.

I still have a little trouble understanding why `onClick = {() => this.onClickDeleteRow (index)}` is correct but not just `this.onClickDeleteRow (index)`.

Comment: Value of the `onClick` prop should be a function, so when you do `onClick={this.onClickDeleteRow (index)}`, you are not passing a function, you are calling the `onClickDeleteRow` function and setting its return value as a value of the `onClick` prop. `onClick` prop needs a function that React can call in response to a click.

Comment: Ok, so it explains this error `Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state`.  Thanks for taking a little of your time to help me, that's really nice of you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call this.state.users in the method

```
  onClickDeleteRow = index => {
        const users = this.state.users;
        users.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({ users: users });  
      };
```